# Wygwam fields disappearing and causing EE 2.9.2 to lock up

Tags: wygwam

I'm having an issue with the latest WygWam Module after moving to a new server and updating to EE 2.9.2. I was on EE 2.2.1 and moved everything over and upgraded about a month ago. Ever since then WygWam has been messing up. I have 2 issues happening.

1. I was first notified about the issue when our client said they couldn't paste in entries anymore without it losing formatting. Basically they were pasting listing information from emails that were submitted to them and on the old server and old version of Wygwam, they could select the text on the email and it would paste in with all formatting in tact. With the upgrade, it was stripping out all formatting and just pasting as plain text.

   So I reuploaded all files and went to the field type settings and under advanced settings I turned off forcePasteAsPlainText and turned on FullPage. I'd prefer to have the formatted code be pasted in without having FullPage on because it adds and extra top and bottom HTML, Head and Body tag to the page when its already got that.But, this seems to fix the issue for the client.
2. However, now when I go to other entries to make edits, the editor will show for a second and then it disappears and locks up the page and I have to close down the tab and go log back in to fix it. On a few entries the editor shows up fine. Here is a screenshot.

   http://screencast.com/t/koUdI5T60z

   I tried to turn on the the defer CK Editor until clicked on, and the editor does show up but the same problem happens once I click on the field.

I'm not sure how to get this working as I've already tried uploading all files again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any errors showing up in the `console.log`? Might want to email P&T on this one if no errors are showing up.

Comment: Where would I find the console.log at? I'm using Chrome for my browser.

Comment: Using Google Chrome and it's inspector tool under console.  That will give you info if there's issues with loading anything.